# Extension optional permissions request: What counts as a user gesture?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to use the `chrome.permissions.request` API to request optional permissions.

However, [chrome.permissions.request](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/permissions/#step-3-request-optional-permissions) requires a user gesture.

What counts as a user gesture? I'm unable to request permissions as a direct response to the extension's page action icon being clicked.

I've tried ensuring that the event handler is synchronous when calling `chrome.permissions.request`, but this does not help. The error I get is:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: This function must be called during a
> user gesture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mozilla has a page describing [user gestures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/User_actions)

They write as follows - to follow the principle of "no surprises", APIs like this can only be called from inside the handler for a user action. User actions include the following:

- Clicking the extension's browser action or page action.
- Selecting a context menu item defined by the extension.
- Activating a keyboard shortcut defined by the extension (this only
  treated as a user action from Firefox 63 onwards).
- Clicking a button in a page bundled with the extension.

Those gestures should be able to activate the request.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Turns out that I'd converted the method to be synchronous, but there was a stray async call that I'd missed